# display ripple effect before executing onclick handler

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a simple ripple effect that runs `.25s` started `onmousedown`.

When the element has a `onclick` handler that navigates to another page the ripple effect is not visible, cause the element is removed by the page transition before it can play the ripple effect.

How can I ensure that at least the start of the effect is visible to the user as visual click feedback?

Comment: Use `setTimeout` to trigger the page transition, 250ms after the click instead of immediately.  If you post the click handler code we can help.

Comment: I tried that of course but it felt like a too long delay.

Comment: Sorry, but that is the answer to the question you've asked.  If you want something else then you're just going to have to play around with the timing.  Have you considered "ajaxifying" the links?  An asynchronous approach to page loading would also resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It's a SPA with `react` so ajax loading is not really an option here.

Comment: If the browser navigation is stopping any animations (which is most likely the case) then you're not going to get around it any other way than the 2 I've already suggested.  Good luck :)